# How do I make a section of code execute if a button is clicked after another button is clicked in visual basic

Tags: vb.net, events, button, click

So basically what the title says.  I want to make a program where you click a button, and then another button shows up, and then if you click the next button in a certain amount of time you get a point.
This is what I found in another thread, but this also makes the timer count down before the second button even shows up, even though this code is after the code making the next button show up.

```
Do While DoWhileBool = True
    Select Case DirectCast(Sender, Button).Name
    Case "ClickHere2"
        If TimeCount > 0 Then
            MultCount += 1
        End If

    Case "ClickHere3"
        If TimeCount > 0 Then
            MultCount += 1
        End If
```

This is not the full code by any means, but I just wanted to show what I tried that doesn't work for having a button click event in an if statement inside another button click method.

Edit:  I ended up figuring it out partially but pretty much all of what I was asking thanks to the help of the answer:

```
NumButTim.Stop()
If TimerVar <> 0 Then
    MultCount += 1
    MultCounter.Text = MultCount
    MultCounter.Refresh()
End If
NumButTim.Start()
TimerVar = 5
'Do Until TimerVar = 0
'    TimerVar = Timer1.ToString
'    TimeCounter.Text = Timer1.ToString
'    TimeCounter.Refresh()
'Loop
```

End Sub

The commented section was where I was trying to get a textbox to show the countdown time, but it doesn't work.  I'm sure I could figure it out if I wanted to, but I've moved on to other things.  Thanks to the person who answered it, he probably led me to the right answer.

Sidenote:  I don't use visual basic anymore, but the idea I had that this was a part of was sort of a mix of clicker game num pad typing and letter key typing and the typing would increase a multiplier for a while.  Never really finished that idea and I don't even know if what I had made in that game even exists anymore because my external hard drive went kaput before I had transferred all the old files onto my current computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i understand of your question, this is how i would do it:

Add a timer, and 2 buttons to the form

On form load, you want to set the interval on the timer, so something like this:

```
Timer1.Interval = 1000       'Set the interval to 1 second
```

Then when you click on the first button show the second button, so on button1 click:

```
Button2.show()               'Show the second button
Timer1.Start()               'Start the timer, so they have 1 second from now
```

And in button 2 click, you want to do your event, add a point etc:

```
points += 1
```

Then to make the second button dissapear, (timeout) after a certian amount of time, you change the interval of the timer1. If the button wants to show for 1 second, set the interval to 1000 (milliseconds)

Then in timer1.tick add this code:

```
timer1.Stop()                'Stop the timer so that its not ran again and again
Button2.Hide()               'Hide the second button
MsgBox("You was too slow!!") 'Tell the user they missed it, or your code..
```

Comment: How would I make a timer?  The way I was doing it was having the timecount variable increment down 1 every time the while loop executed.  I get what you said about putting the increment in the second button, but I'm just not sure if Timer1 is supposed to be a variable or something else?

Comment: Timer1 will be a timer object, added from the toolbox in design view (I am assuming you are using the design view and not creating all objects dynamically in code?)

Comment: Yes I am using the form project and I do use the design view to get all my objects in the program.  Thanks I will try what you have said here and then come back and say if it worked.

Comment: Ok another question to clarify, would tick be another method?  Also, how would I show the time as it counts down on the form?